# Does Go fix or share C's hazardous implicit -> unsigned conversion?

Tags: c, go, types, unsigned, signed

In "21st Century C", Ben Klemens describes how C automatically converts signed numbers to unsigned, in comparison expressions for example. Does Go share this same hazardous behavior, or does Go approach it differently?

Answer (score 2):

There are no implicit conversions in Go. In order to compare or do arithmetic with two values of different types, you must do manual and explicit type conversion.

```
a := 3          // numerical constant 3 defaults to int
b := uint(2)
c := a < b      // compiler error
d := a < int(b) // OK
```

Answer (score 2):

Go uses only [explicit type conversions](https://tour.golang.org/basics/13) for all the operations including comparison.

```
var a uint64
var b int64

a = 1
b = 1
if a == b {
    fmt.Println("Equal")
}
```

This snippet is going to cause an error:

> tmp/sandbox428200464/main.go:13: invalid operation: a == b (mismatched types uint64 and int64)

To do the comparison you must cast the variables to the same type explicitly:

```
if int64(a) == b {...}
```

So, definitely **yes**, it is fixed if one can say so.

[Playgound](https://play.golang.org/p/fa3_4Dd4IC) for the snippet.